# Do Asian giant hornets (Vespa mandarinia) prey on other nests of Asian giant hornets?

Tags: entomology, ecology, predation

Asian giant hornets are known to attack nests of other bees and wasps, but should they encounter another nest of their own, would they attack it?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. According to this [clip](https://youtu.be/sJ5ymto8lWg) uploaded to YouTube on the Smithsonian channel, Asian giant hornets will attack and pillage other nests (of Asian Giant Hornets) if no other food source is readily available.